# Can Entity Framework produce a mapping from foreign key to a GUID in the parent table?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

My database has two table like this (with some columns removed to keep it simple)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question] (
    [QuestionId]       INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ProblemId]        INT              NOT NULL,
    [QuestionUId]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Question] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QuestionId] ASC)
);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Question_QuestionUId_UIX]
    ON [dbo].[Question]([QuestionUId] ASC);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdminTestQuestion] (
    [AdminTestQuestionId] INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AdminTestId]         INT              NOT NULL,
    [QuestionNumber]      INT              NOT NULL,
    [QuestionUId]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AdminTestQuestion] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AdminTestQuestionId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AdminTestQuestionQuestionUId] FOREIGN KEY ([QuestionUId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Question] ([QuestionUId])
);
```

When I run the Entity Framework Reverse engineer it does not create a mapping from AdminTestQuestion > Question
and it does not create a collection of AdminTestQuestions in Question class. I was hoping to see something like this but from what I understand it has difficulty when one end of the foreign key is a GUID.

```
public partial class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        this.Answers = new List<AdminTestQuestion>();
    }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int ProblemId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid QuestionUId { get; set; }
}
```

I also expected mapping information something like this in AdminTestQuestion mapping file:

```
        this.HasRequired(t => t.QuestionUId)
            .With????(t => t.Questions)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.QuestionUId);
```

Can anyone advise me can I create this kind of mapping to a GUID with EF6+ ?

Comment: are the other relationships in your database which create the mappings between GUIDs?

Comment: MAybe it is just me but why aren;t you using QuestionID as teh FK field? JOins are going to be much faster on integers than guids. I don;t understnd why you have the GUID field at all to be honest since you have a differnt PK on teh primary table. What is the GUID getting you?

Comment: The QuestionId is for internal use only.  The QuestionUId is visible to everyone.  Unfortunately I am only allowed to link to the QuestionUId.

Comment: [Unique Constraint (i.e. Candidate Key) Support](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support) _We are working on unique constraint support in EF7._ - comment of the admin

Comment: But with EF7 Will I be able to link to a Unique System.Guid ?

Comment: The FK should still be the QuestionID.  You can still choose to display the GUID to the user if you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way of doing this with EF6, as it has no knowledge of the Unique index on the QuestionUId column. The only way to do this is to make QuestionUId a primary key in the Question table, and I see nothing preventing you from doing so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question] (
    [QuestionId]       INT              IDENTITY (1, 1)  NOT NULL,
    [ProblemId]        INT              NOT NULL,
    [QuestionUId]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Question] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QuestionUId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdminTestQuestion] (
    [AdminTestQuestionId] INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AdminTestId]         INT              NOT NULL,
    [QuestionNumber]      INT              NOT NULL,
    [QuestionUId]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AdminTestQuestion] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AdminTestQuestionId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AdminTestQuestionQuestionUId] FOREIGN KEY ([QuestionUId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Question] ([QuestionUId])
);
```

Which generates (using Code First from Database):

```
public partial class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        AdminTestQuestion = new HashSet<AdminTestQuestion>();
    }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int ProblemId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Guid QuestionUId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AdminTestQuestion> AdminTestQuestion { get; set; }
}

public partial class AdminTestQuestion
{
    public int AdminTestQuestionId { get; set; }
    public int AdminTestId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionNumber { get; set; }
    public Guid QuestionUId { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
    .HasMany(e => e.AdminTestQuestion)
    .WithRequired(e => e.Question)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Erik. Did I see you mention something about this being fixed in 6.1.2.  I can easily upgrade to that if it would help.

Comment: Yes, but the fix in 6,1,2 does not solve your issue, sadly https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/667

Comment: How about EF7 or it a bit too early to be asking that question?

Comment: Yes, I think it could possibly Work in EF7, as Indexes are now part of the model, so EF has knowledge about them